# Check if other Side does a redirect to login Page

Tags: javascript, cookies, xmlhttprequest

I have currently a Problem, where i need to check whether user is logged in on an other side or not. Since i cannot access cookies from other domains, it came to my mind, than i can make a XHR-GET to the Content to the side and if the user is not logged in then it will redirect me to login. But it seems that in xhr those cookies are not set either and it always redirects me to login.

here is my xhr:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://business-factory.mykajabi.com/library",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
      },
  })
    .done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data)
    });
```

Comment: You will need some sort of coherent logic between the 2 sites, i.e. a shared database variable to check if the user is logged in to one site or the other, or some sort of other server messaging. Another option is an API that connects the 2 sites. Depending on the websites, they could use a unified login method, in which case you can query for that to check if the user is logged in or not. Are you the owner of both sites, or do you have to check for external domains that you do not have access to? By access I mean programatically.

Comment: no unfortunately i only can access the Side from which i am running the xhr....

Comment: Then there is no way outside of API really, which will need cooperation between you and the owner of the external site(s), or have the other sites contain custom cookies that you can compare on your own site.

Comment: the fact that you can't do this without the co-operation of the other site is a good thing, just part of a secure web - I don't want your site knowing what sites I have logins for